# How to get Long (data type) value back from redis cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis-cache

I am storing userId as Long in redis cache in my spring boot application but while retrieving it returns Integer type and throws exception

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Below is the code snippet I am using.

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.GAUTH_CACHE, key = "#root.target.PASSWORD_SALT.concat(#loginTxt.toString())", unless = "#result == null")
    public Long getPasswordSaltFromLoginText(String loginTxt) {
        Long userId = null;
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(loginTxt)) {
            userId =  profileRepository.getUserIdForPasswordSalt(loginTxt, "PasswordSalt");
        }
        return userId;
    }
```

My Hibernate query is something like that. in which  `A.USR_ID` is type `Long`

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select A.USR_ID from user_tbl A, another_table B WHERE A.USR_ID = B.USR_ID AND "
            + " UPPER(A.loginTxt) = UPPER(:loginTxt) "
            + " AND B.prefName=:prefName ")

    Long getUserId(@Param("loginTxt") String loginTxt, @Param("prefName") String prefName);
```

Entity class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table1", schema = "Schema_name")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @Column(name="USR_Id")
    public Long USR_ID;

    @Column(name="other_column")
    public Long other_column;

    @Column(name="other_column2")
    public Long other_column2;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're storing it as a `Long`?

Comment: Yes, you can see the code in which userid is stored as Long

Comment: What's the exact database type of `A.USR_ID`?

Comment: In DataBase A.USR_ID datatype is NUMBER

Comment: Well, that _might_ actually be mapped to `Integer` internally (and could be put into the cache that way). What database are you using?

Comment: I think you are correct. I am using Oracle database. Is there any way to do it in JPA or in nativequery so that it can return Long?

Comment: Well using JPA mapping it to `Long` and loading the data via entities should work.

Comment: could you please give small example? it would be great help.

Comment: Didn't you already map your data to JPA entities? If not I'd suggest grabbing a tutorial on that - a small example might not be sufficient in that case.

Comment: I have already done that but it didn't work. I am going to add my entity class here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis cache doesn't support the Long data type. So I have stored whole profile object into redis cache and using `getter()`, I was able to get the Long value.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select A.USR_ID,A.other_column,A.other_column2 from user_tbl A, another_table B WHERE A.USR_ID = B.USR_ID AND "
            + " UPPER(A.loginTxt) = UPPER(:loginTxt) "
            + " AND B.prefName=:prefName ")

    Profile getUserId(@Param("loginTxt") String loginTxt, @Param("prefName") String prefName);
```